# Taking periodic backups of a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, backup

I need to know how can I backup my MySQL databases on a periodic basis and have the backups downloaded to my local server. I'm using navicat and it has an easy backup interface and tasks schedule facility but it backs up the db and stores the backup on the server itself. I would like to have a way to download the backups once made to my local system rather than have them on the same server as the database.

Comment: Might be more suitable on serverfault?

Comment: You should also take a look at: http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start

Comment: i have a mysql database of 2000 GB. i every week about 10GB of Data is added. i have backup of the 2000 GB i just want to take the Backup of newly Added Data

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setup a server cron which runs mysqldump command after some interval (e.g. 24 hours)

```
mysqldump -hMY_HOST.COM -uDB_USERNAME -pDB_PASSWORD USERNAME_DATABASENAME > MysqlDump.sql
```

After creating dump file. Setup another cron to copy this dump to target server(preferably local) make this execute with same interval of above cron.

```
scp user@MY_HOST.COM:/some/path/file user2@MY_HOST2.COM:/some/path/file
```

**NOTE: This commands may cause high server load (make sure you are executing them when server having minimum load)**

Comment: i have a mysql database of 2000 GB. i every week about 10GB of Data is added. i have backup of the 2000 GB i just want to take the Backup of newly Added Data

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mysqldump, there are a few other backup options. These are mainly to work around the mysqldump causes highload/long reload times.

1. There's [InnoDB hot backup](http://www.innodb.com/products/hot-backup/order/), it's a pay product by the makers of InnoDB to backup in an online fashion. It's also harder to backup InnoDB tables than MyISAM, because with the latter, if the table is flushed, you can just copy the files, but the former has issues.

   - If your backup's can take instantaneous snapshots of your harddrive, [FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) will flush out your writes to disk so your backups are in a consistent state. However, this will block all reads, until your done, so if they aren't instantaneous, it won't be good.

Comment: i have a mysql database of 2000 GB. i every week about 10GB of Data is added. i have backup of the 2000 GB i just want to take the Backup of newly Added Data

Answer (score -1):

You should try mydumper - https://answers.launchpad.net/mydumper/+faq/338

It has a daemon mode that can take periodic backups for you and was developed by some excellent MySQL engineers.  I believe it has been billed as mysqldump as a dba would imagine it ; )

Comment: i have a mysql database of 2000 GB. i every week about 10GB of Data is added. i have backup of the 2000 GB i just want to take the Backup of newly Added Data